# User app that runs in background and continuously loops to read from hidraw randomly crashes

Tags: c++, linux, input, io, hid

I wrote a user space application that essentially just continuously loops to read from a custom HID device through the hidraw module.  I want to read incoming data from the device, process that data and then inject user input events into the user input stream based on the processed data such that the device can be used to control the pointer and simulate custom keystroke combinations.  I wrote a udev rule so that the application is launched automatically and runs in the background when my device is plugged into the PC via USB.  I have everything working really well except for the fact that it crashes randomly after about 10 minutes of use.  I set up a log process that just consists of printing status statements to a log file and when I examine this after the app crashes it looks like the app crashed in the middle of printing a line to the log file.  It's like the application is getting kicked off the cpu/killed but I'm not sure why or how or by what. I feel like I'm just missing something obvious/right in front of me but I can't figure out what it is.  I've tried it with a separate read thread with the same result.  Any thoughts?

Comment: So did you try any debugging, like attaching gdb to it once it gets started up?

Comment: No, but I will...I was kind of hoping something obvious would jump out at someone

Comment: You have a bug in your program. There is nothing wrong with your logging, you're just seeing the internal stdlib I/O buffering. Turn that off or flush it more often if you want accurate log output, but only gdb or similar debugging is going to find the real issue.

Comment: Oh, no, I know there's nothing wrong with the log, I just did that so I could quickly see where the program was exiting in case a function call returned an error that I wasn't expecting and caused the program to terminate but it looks like it is just being killed mid-process.  It seems to run just fine if I launch it from a terminal but it gets killed after 5-10mins if it automatically launches/runs in the background. Thanks for the responses, btw, I appreciate the feedback. I'm currently running it through gdb and waiting for the crash to happen (hasn't happened yet after about 1 hour)